# Updating the model classes after a change to the database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-design

I have quite a noob question, but please bear with me. Imagine we have a database (MS SQL here) with all the tables defined etc. and I decide to add a new column to one of the tables.
I do that "directly" in SQL Server - I right-click on the table I want to change, select Design and then I add one column to that table.
Now, how do I "update" the corresponding model class of my ASP.NET application? If I understand correctly, I need to re-scaffold the database and this will be automatically updated? How do I proceed with this? My application targets .NetCore 3.1 and I am using EF Core 3.1.8.
Thank you.

Comment: just use EF migrations instead. change the models first then apply EF migrations-Database update,  you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#evolving-your-model)

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can also help you with this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you're using is a Database first approach, Meaning the Database decides how your models will look like. To apply updates from your database you'll need to re-scaffold the dbcontext. (Note: You might need to use -f force flag). Check the links below for more info.

https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-database-first

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/pmc-commands#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: Or just add a new property to your entity.